# Why does this objective-c exception backtrace show only the last two calls?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, llvm

Using Xcode (4.3.3 and llvm), I set a breakpoint on all exceptions but often when the breakpoint is hit, the stack looks like this:

```
(lldb) bt
* thread #1: tid = 0x1c03, 0x31a891c4 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_exception_throw, stop reason = breakpoint 1.1
    frame #0: 0x31a891c4 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_exception_throw
    frame #1: 0x33a677b8 CoreFoundation`+[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 100
```

There's no information about the caller of `NSException raise:format:arguments:`, the stack just stops there.

Something must have called raise so what happened to the stack?  What should I look for to help me debug such issues (e.g. does this indicate some specific type of stack corruption or something else)?

**Update:** here's the code with the garbage.

The problem was that I accidentally wrote %s when I meant %@.  Might have been a bit of a stretch to call that a properly-allocated string but I could "po imageName" in the llvm console, it just had some garbage at the end.

```
NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"award_%s", award];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
[_awardIconMapping setObject:image forKey:award];
```

There was no thread #0 by the time the exception was hit.  Using @try/@catch, I get a sensible exception from the last line (sorry, I thought it was the image= line before):

```
2012-07-06 10:43:36.184 CallVille[834:707] ****** Hit exception ********
-[__NSCFDictionary setObject:forKey:]: attempt to insert nil value (key: wiseGuy)
```

Comment: PS. If it helps, this particular failure was caused by calling `NSImage imageWithName:` with a (properly-allocated) string containing some garbage.

Comment: There is a thread #0, which usually creates thread #1. Can you show the code with the garbage? Have you tried to surround it with @try ... @catch?

Comment: I've updated the post with answers.

Comment: I got the code working and, when I catch the exception, I can print the exception detail.  But what I really want is a reliable way to get meaningful stack traces when things go wrong.  Every other language I've worked with (C, Java, C++, all dynamic languages) can do that, what am I missing!?

Answer (score 0):

I use this function to print the stack traces from a NSException:

```
#include <execinfo.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

+ (void) printStackTrace: (NSException*) e
{
    NSArray * addresses = [e callStackReturnAddresses];
    if( [addresses count])
    {
        void * backtrace_frames[[addresses count]];
        int i = 0;
        for (NSNumber * address in addresses)
        {
            backtrace_frames[i] = (void *)[address unsignedLongValue];
            i++;
        }

        char **frameStrings = backtrace_symbols(&backtrace_frames[0], [addresses count]);

        if(frameStrings != NULL)
        {
            int x;
            for(x = 0; x < [addresses count]; x++)
            {
                NSString *frame_description = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:frameStrings[ x]];
                NSLog( @"------- %@", frame_description);
            }
            free( frameStrings);
            frameStrings = nil;
        }
    }
}
```